# Adding extra info to order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am programmatically adding a product to the cart. Besides this, somehow, I want to store some extra info (an array) to the order. When the client finishes the order, I want to access that info through some WordPress actions. I'll have to do this immediately after adding the product to the cart, because the info may change after that, if the user doesn't finish the order right away. Is there any way I can do it, without putting the database to work?

Comment: Can you use the `$_SESSION` array?

Comment: @rnevius Yes, that would be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the `WooCommerce Cart Item Meta API` and the `WooCommerce Order Item Meta API`.

You use them like this:

```
// Add to cart item
// This is triggered on add to cart
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'my_add_cart_item_data', 10, 2);

function my_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_meta, $product_id ) {

    //Here we can easily filter what values should be added to what products using the $product_id 
    $cart_item_meta['my_meta_key'] = 'meta value';

    return $cart_item_meta;
}

// Add to order item when the cart is converted to an order
// This is triggered when the order is created
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'my_order_item_meta'), 10, 2);

function my_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {

    // The value stored in cart above is accessable in $values here
    woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'meta_key', $values['my_meta_key'] );    

    //Or add what ever you want
    $meta_value = 'value';
    woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'meta_key', $meta_value );   
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll try this today and let you know the result. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello @AmarSyla. Did you try the code? Did it work as you wanted?